# "could not deploy due to insufficient funds", but still I have 0.000052197965366494 Ether. How could I solve this error?

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, ropsten, infura

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  0xDBC7A8105d32E4d6a80De11A94b0583047A7dbA5
   * Balance:  52197965366494 wei
   * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:70:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:56:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:217:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:76:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:44:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.4.26 (core: 5.4.26)
Node v14.18.2
```

Comment: I dont think that amount of ether is enough, try checking the deployment cost first and see if you really have insufficient funds

Comment: What does the deployment script do? How much gas is used by the contract? What is the gas priced used?

Comment: I got it,thanks all. due to insufficient faund I faced this error.